# Caching using Memcached and python-memcache

Tags: python, django, caching

I installed them both, but i get a None every time i try to get some key

```
>>from django.core.cache import cache #no errors
>>cache.set('value1','value2',39) #no errors
>>cache.get('value1') #no errors but no value either
```

in settings.py i got

```
CACHES = {
'default':{
    'BACKEND':'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
    'LOCATION':'127.0.0.1:1991',
    'TIMEOUT': 1200,
    }
}
```

what is going on wrong? I don't have even the slightest idea what to debug or where to start ...

Comment: You say you installed them both.  Is the memcached server running?

Comment: bah dum tsssssss! How to start it on my dev machine ? Was not in the docs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that memcached is actually running, and that it is configured to listen on 127.0.0.1 port 1991? By default memcached listens on port 11211.

`django.core.cache.cache` plays dumb when `memcache` fails to store keys, it doesn't raise an exception or return any error.

You can test more directly with memcache like this:

```
import memcache

for port in (1991, 11211):
    print "Testing memcached on port %d" % port
    mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:%d' % port])

    if mc.set('value1', 'value2'):
        print "stored key value pair"
        if mc.get('value1') == 'value2':
            print "successfully retrieved value"
            break
        else:
            print "Failed to retrieve value"
    else:
        print "Failed to store key value pair"
```

Comment: like i said in my other comment, how to start the memcache server on my dev machine? plus how to configure it to the different port?

Comment: `man memcached`? Simply `memcached` will start it up listening on port 11211 on all interfaces on the local machine. Use `memcached -p 1991` to use port 1991. Add the `-vv` option to see lots of logging.